# What type of statistics is used to describe this chart?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-visualization

What kind of data analysis technique / formula would you use to describe which is the fastest OS in this chart, Windows or Linux?

[image]

If Linux and Windows had equal speed on all tests, all bars would be 50% blue, 50% green.

The data is duration in milliseconds. Each number (e.g. Linux Startup) represents the mean of 1000 individual duration tests on that scenario. The results of each test individually is covered in separate charts.

This data represents an overview of the one set of data (Linux over the course of these 5 tests) and how it relates to the second set of data (Windows over the course of these 5 tests). The aim is to be able to say:

Over the 5 tests we Windows is faster. (You can see this in the chart because there is less green, but this is to prove it statistically).

Note:

The chart below shows the same data in real value terms, showing that one test dominates the others. While this is an important result, it does not weigh on the current question as the two results in the 'Refreshing Desktop' test still bear the same relation to each other as those in the other tests.

In the comments there has been some discussion on how to represent this data. The reason I represent it in stacked bars is because I want to show it *without* the overshadowing effect of the one anomalous data. Is there a preferred method to show this relationship?

[image]

Comment: This chart is meaningless to me because the vertical axis is unlabeled and I have no clue what, say, a 40% "like" would be.  The only data analysis technique I know of that describes this graphic is [chartjunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk) (and it's a super example of the species).

Comment: Ok, made a new chart, didnt think the last one through properly.

Comment: Thanks. It's still not apparent what the vertical axis represents.  Obviously it's not startup times, despite the claim in the title.

Comment: @gung, The percentages are not important, it's more important to have a marked in the middle (50%) to show where the line would be if the two sides (top and bottom) were equal. I.e. the two data relative to each other.

Comment: I don't see why you would be using a stacked bar chart here. If these are times, why not have time on the Y axis & present the 2 bars side by side for each test. Setting that issue aside, Yes, you can average the 5 conditions, but there is a philosophical issue here as well: Are all situations equally important (ie, should you be using a weighted average, eg)?

Comment: @gung, have made a more representative chart. All situations are equally important.

Comment: @gung That's more than a mere philosophical issue: it gets to the core reason why no statistical analysis can demonstrate the correctness of the desired conclusion. If one system is faster than the other *on just a single test* but otherwise is slower, it is still that case that people who highly value that one test would emphasize it to the complete neglect of all the others.  This is an example of a [multi-attribute valuation problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multi+attribute+valuation).

Comment: With the latest edit the chart has moved from the sublime to the ridiculous: the heights of the bars are meaningless (or else each is plotted on its own private axis, which is plain confusing). The chart should be replaced by the table of ten numbers (suitably rounded, one would hope) and left at that. It's just getting in the way of formulating an answerable question.

Comment: Absolutely, and that is the overall point, but one still needs to be able to say that technically, i.e. statistically speaking, over the 5 tests, Windows is faster.

Comment: @whuber, The bars are to visually represent relativity to each other over each test.

Comment: @Jack, *stacking* the bars impedes their ability to "visually represent relativity to each other over each test". Put them side by side. See my answer [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot/17724625#17724625) for an example.

Comment: @gung, I used stacking purely to display relationship of data. The actual quantity (duration) is irrelevant

Comment: Would it make more sense to use a graph where the values are radiating horizontally from the centre? Not sure what that one is called. But this is just how to represent the data. Is there any meaningful statistical analysis that I can apply to the dataset?

Comment: This is *much* better. The fact that the times for one of the tests overwhelms all the others is **important** information. The question of how (& whether!) the tests should be put on the same scale is one of data transformation. Note that by placing them within the same range, even though they didn't start out that way, *is* a form of weighting.

Comment: Because you haven't yet described the dataset, Jack, there is no way this question can be answered. Where do the numbers come from? How many tests do they represent? Are they means, medians, maxima, something else? Were the tests conducted independently of each other?  It's also still unclear what you really mean by one system being "faster" than another, but that has to be made specific and quantitative for there to be any hope of applying statistical methods.

Comment: @gung, the fact that one overwhelms the others is referenced in a different chart. This is to show relationships. I agree it is weighted like this.

Comment: @whuber, They are gathered data. Each number represents the mean of 1000 duration tests. All tests are independent, but representing aspects of the whole (speed of the operating system). The individual tests are described in their own charts separately, whereas this is an overall view. Taking the averages and weighing them against each other, it's averaging the faster operating system over the 5 different scenarios.

Comment: At this point nobody is going to read this essential information you just gave, Jack: not through any fault of yours but because it's buried so deep into the comments. Please edit your question so that everything needed to answer it is contained in the question itself.  (Many of these comments will eventually be deleted in order to clean up the thread.)

Comment: Jack - you said "*I used stacking purely to display relationship of data. The actual quantity (duration) is irrelevant*". Stacking makes the length comparison difficult. If the values don't matter, [plot the logs of the ratios instead](http://i.imgur.com/7JdyTki.png) (but with axes representing the percentage difference). With your plot, you can't get nearly the comparative information out that's in that linked plot.

Comment: @Glen_b, ratio is the key here, I agree

Comment: @Glen_b, could you expand on your log plotting in an answer? The question is what kind of statistical analysis can be performed on this data and your answer is certainly valid and a better way of presenting the data. I'm not sure on how to approach it so would greatly appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Displaying the results**

You said in comments

> I used stacking purely to display relationship of data. The actual quantity (duration) is irrelevant

Stacking makes the length comparison difficult; for the ones that are close together in time, you'd need to look at the numbers to see a difference. If the values don't matter, one option is to plot the logs of the ratios instead (but with axes representing the percentage difference)

With a plot more like this:

[image: log-ratio plot]

you get a better sense of the relative speed of the various tasks under the two systems.

However, it may be worth looking at plots where all of the individual values are represented (rather than just averages), so that an idea of the relative variability is also available.

**Testing for a difference**

The issue with any kind of statistical test is being very precise about what it is we mean to test.

In particular, what null and alternative hypothesis we're dealing with, and under what assumptions.

You have 5 numbers for each type of activity - are they just repetitions, or is there some kind of pairing across 5 different circumstances? Are you looking for a test within each kind of activity or something overall?

---

R code to (approximately) generate the above plot:

```
wl <- read.table(stdin(),header=TRUE)
Linux Windows Scenario
1.962 1.415 "Startup"
8.469 6.996 "Shutdown"
102.2 79.3 "RefreshDesktop"
1.777 2.866 "AccessInternet"
1.259 1.165 "WebcamStartup"

wl2 <- as.matrix(data.frame(wl[,1:2],row.names=wl[,3]))
wl3 <- wl2[,2]/wl2[,1]
opar <- par()
par(xaxt="n")
dotchart(log(wl3))
abline(v=0,col=8,lwd=2)
axis(side=1, at=log(c(1/1.6,1/1.4,1/1.2,1,1.2,1.4,1.6)),
    labels=c("60%","40%","20%","same","20%","40%","60%"),xaxt="s")
title(main="Relative speed of Windows and Linux",
   sub="             Linux slower by                        Windows slower by")
par(opar)
```